# (VueJS) Vuex getter should update based on another module state change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two Vuex store modules: `ListItems` and `ListSort`.  `ListItems` has a getter that is essentially computed from the state of both of these modules.  See the below code:

```
// Import the ListSort store module
import listSort from './list-sort';

// ListItems getters
const getters = {
  companiesSorted: () => {
    return _.orderBy(state.companies,
      [listSort.state.sortAttribute],
      [listSort.state.sortDirection]);
  },
};
```

However, when the state in `ListSort` is changed (i.e. `sortAttribute` or `sortDirection` are changed), this is not causing the ListItems getter to recompute.  How can I tell Vuex that, given a dependency to computing `companiesStored` has changed, Vuex should recompute that getter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell Vuex that, given a dependency to computing
>   companiesStored has changed, Vuex should recompute that getter?

You don't, it's done automatically for you! Isn't Vue awesome for lazy developers?

The only JS module that should import a Vuex module is the JS module that initializes Vuex, thru `new Vuex.Store`, which bundles the Vuex modules together.

Vuex module getters have access to their local `state`, and the `rootState`. The `rootState` is where you access other module's data.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#module-local-state

It should look something like this:

```
companiesSorted: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    return _.orderBy(state.companies,
      [rootState.listSortModule.sortAttribute],
      [rootState.listSortModule.sortDirection]);
  },
```

Where `listSortModule` is the name you gave to the module.